# Hibernate 4.1Final alternative for Hibernate.STRING

Tags: java, hibernate

I was using Hibernate 3.6 where I have a code like this:

```
list =getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString)
        .addScalar("UNAME",Hibernate.STRING)
        .addScalar("COM",Hibernate.STRING)
        .addScalar("COM_DATE",Hibernate.DATE) 
        .setString("id", Id).list();
```

now I change the jar from 3.6 to 4.1Final

it seems like the addScalar method is askying for Type in stead of Hibernate.STRING
I couldn't find any example hot to resolve this. if there is anyone that who know please help me thank you.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Type fields in [org.hibernate.Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html) are deprecated (and actually removed) as result of [HHH-5196](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5196)

Now different Hibernate types can be found from javadocs for [Type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/Type.html). In your case following should work:

```
    .addScalar("UNAME", StringType.INSTANCE)
    .addScalar("COM", StringType.INSTANCE)
    .addScalar("COM_DATE", DateType.INSTANCE)
```

Comment: Instead of `Hibernate.STRING` one can use `StandardBasicTypes.STRING` also, the value is the same (`StringType.INSTANCE`), maybe this one is easier for merge ;-)