# hibernate-spatial: sql query to retrieve a geometry

Tags: hibernate, geometry, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I'm using postgresql, hibernate-spatial and postgis and expected to be able to use a SqlQuery to retrieve a Geometry object.

However whenever I try to query a Point, Polygon or Geometry eg

```
List list = session.createSQLQuery(
    "select geomfromewkt('SRID=1;POINT(1 1)')").list();
```

I get the exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:590)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:516)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:532)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1962)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernatespatial.postgis.PostgisDialect</property>
```

Is this not part of the hibernate-spatial offering or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks, Paul.

Relevant libraries/versions:

- hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar
- postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar
- hibernate-spatial-postgis-1.1.1.jar
- hibernate-spatial-1.1.1.jar
- postgis-jdbc-1.3.3.jar
- jts-1.12.jar

Comment: Is the DB spatially enabledand have the correct privileges? From the client, try `select * from geometry_columns`

Comment: Yes the DB is all fine. I can retrieve geometries via hibernate if using mapped classes and non-native-sql type queries (criteria/hsql).

Comment: I'm sure I have to apply the 'org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType' to the column somehow...

Answer (score 6):

I've figured it out. I need to apply the 'GeometryUserType' to the column via a scalar.

```
SQLQuery qry = session.createSQLQuery("select geomfromewkt('SRID=1;POINT(1 1)') as geom");
qry.addScalar("geom", GeometryUserType.TYPE);
List<Geometry> list = qry.list();
```

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10256646/1228324) some types were deprecated and thus removed in Hibernate 4+. Instead of `GeometryUserType.TYPE` I had to use `org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType.INSTANCE` in Hibernate 4.1.4.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Hibernate 5.1.0 Final,

```
dao.getSession().createSQLQuery("select buffer from puntosdeinteres where puntoid = 13193")
                        .addScalar("buffer", new GeolatteGeometryType(PGGeometryTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE))
                        .uniqueResult();
```

And it works, but right now I find that long statement uncomfortable.