# What does addScalar do?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, scalar

The JavaDoc says:

```
SQLQuery org.hibernate.SQLQuery.addScalar(String columnAlias, Type type)

Declare a scalar query result
```

I know what `executeScalar` is in C#, but this scalar and C# scalar seem to be absolutely different.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is declaring that you want the result of the query to return objects for individual named columns, rather than entities. For instance

```
createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM Users").addScalar("c").uniqueResult()
```

Will return a single `Long`. If you specify multiple scalars, the result will come back as an array of `Object`. Its similar to `executeScalar` except that it works on named columns, and can return a composite result.

Answer (score 19):

To avoid the overhead of using ResultSetMetadata, or simply to be more explicit in what is returned, one can use addScalar():

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS")
.addScalar("ID", Hibernate.LONG)
.addScalar("NAME", Hibernate.STRING)
.addScalar("BIRTHDATE", Hibernate.DATE)
```

This query specified:

```
the SQL query string
the columns and types to return
```

This will return Object arrays, but now it will not use ResultSetMetadata but will instead explicitly get the ID, NAME and BIRTHDATE column as respectively a Long, String and a Short from the underlying resultset. This also means that only these three columns will be returned, even though the query is using * and could return more than the three listed columns.

It is possible to leave out the type information for all or some of the scalars.

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS")
.addScalar("ID", Hibernate.LONG)
.addScalar("NAME")
.addScalar("BIRTHDATE")
```

This is essentially the same query as before, but now ResultSetMetaData is used to determine the type of NAME and BIRTHDATE, where as the type of ID is explicitly specified.

copied from [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13646).

Comment: @IrfanNasim: These type field seem to be deprecated in recent Hibernate versions. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10256646/1228324). Now you should use `LongType.INSTANCE` instead of `Hibernate.LONG`.

Comment: @Evan Is there a way where I can only do addScalar(columnName, type) for some of the columns but the query result should have all the fields since I specified `*` in the select query ? So my problem is, in my PostgreSQL, the datatype of the field is `bigserial` and which translates to `BigInteger` in my Java code. But my POJO classes had those fields as Long, so I specified types of those `Long` fields using `addScalar(...)` but now my query returns only those limited fields. I am not able to find a way out. Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

`addScalar` is an information of returnType for a given key in SQL query.

Example:

```
Query a = new SqlQuery("Select username as un from users where ...");
a.addScalar("un", String);
```

If you query for result, the result will be String or other types if you specify.

Answer (score 1):

This is used when your bean has multiple fields with diff types and you want to get these fields in same type from mysql.
eg.

```
public class Example { Long id; String name; }
```

you can use add scalar as follows

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM tableName")
.addScalar("id", Hibernate.LONG)
.addScalar("name", Hibernate.STRING);
```