# Need to use just Oracle Sequence via hibernate, to generate unique sequential file name

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I am making a program that makes a file and gives it a unique name.
As per the propose technology, we need to have sequential file name.
ex. Myfile-00001 (format : MyFile-Sequence).
I am using oracle sequence to maintain the sequence number for the file name.

Below is the sample code I am trying to write to get just the sequence out of oracle sequence.
If I can get just the string of sequence out of Oracle sequence, I can use it to namemy file I am creating.

Below is my Code:

```
public class TestSequence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure();
        SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session ses = sf.openSession();
        System.out.println("Next Val: "+getNextKey(ses));
    ses.close();
    sf.close();
    }

    public static String getNextKey(Session ses)
    {
        Query query = ses.createSQLQuery( "select atl_seq.nextval from dual" );
        String key = (String) query.uniqueResult();
        return key;
    }
    }
```

But its giving me error:

```
    Next Val: 
Hibernate: select atl_seq.nextval from dual
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at test.TestSequence.getNextKey(TestSequence.java:31)
    at test.TestSequence.main(TestSequence.java:23)
```

Please help how do I convert the unique result into string.
No Mapping file is used, as I am running the query directly.

I have googled a lot and found similar example, they cast the unique result into Long, but even that code is not running  and it gives me same error :cannot cast [Ljava.lang.Object to Long.

My sequence is :

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE   "ATL_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 100 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 48
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [**addScalar()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386571/what-does-addscalar-do) and specify type as `Long` (for **Hibernate4**)

```
public static Long getNextKey(Session ses) {
     Query query = ses.createSQLQuery("select atl_seq.nextval as num from dual") 
                        .addScalar("num", LongType.INSTANCE);
     return (Long)query.uniqueResult();
 }
```

If you are using **Hibernate3**, type should be

```
addScalar("num", Hibernate.LONG);
```

You can convert the value `Long` to `String` later.

Answer (score 0):

Sequence probably returns a long or integer. So you need to cast to that and not to a string!

```
Long key = (Long) query.uniqueResult();
```

or

```
Integer key = (Integer) query.uniqueResult();
```

Don't know which one it is but easy to try for yourself.

Comment: have tried that too.
Its giving me same error ,in above cases its :
if I use Integer casting :
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
If I use Long casting :
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.Long