# Hibernate Criteria with custom database function

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm using Hibernate 4 with PostgreSQL 9.
I want to filter rows with a custom postgres function which looks as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name % ?
```

(I am using the trigram search, a postgres extension).

To use this function with `session.CreateQuery()`, I implemented my own `SQLFunction` and `PostgreSQLDialect` following [this tutorial](https://marzapol.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/custom-function-is-hibernate/).

The function works and looks as follows:

```
session.createQuery("FROM Customer WHERE trgm_match(name, :name) = true");
```

**Now to the difficult part:**

I need to query the table using several search criteria and want to use Hibernate's `Criteria`. How I can I use this custom PostgreSQL function in `criteria.add(Restrictions. ?? );`

I think that `add( Restrictions.sqlRestriction("name % ?", filter, ??) );` might be sufficient, but what should I pass as the third argument? (The column has type `VARCHAR`)

I often saw the usage of `Hibernate.STRING` which doesn't seem to exist in Hibernate 4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `Hibernate.STRING` is deprecated: [Hibernate 4.1Final alternative for Hibernate.STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255506/hibernate-4-1final-alternative-for-hibernate-string)

The following statement works, but it would be nicer to get a solution with a custom Restriction class:

```
add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("name % ?", filter, StringType.INSTANCE));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try creating some restrictions first in a form of a `Predicate` list. Here's an example from my code:

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

//add predicates based on your business logic
if (model.getCreateDateFrom() != null)            
predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(event.get(Event_.createDate), 
                    model.getCreateDateFrom()));

...
//add predicate utilizing your DB function
//0.00001111111 ~= 1 meter
if (model.getLatitude() != null)
    predicates.add(cb.equal(cb.function("is_point_inside_circle", Boolean.class, 
    cb.literal(model.getLatitude()), cb.literal(model.getLongitude()),
    event.get(Event_.latitude), event.get(Event_.longitude), 
    cb.literal(model.getRadius() * 0.00001111111)), true));

//set 'where' clause by converting list to array
cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));

//perform query
//...
```

Read also here: [JPA Criteria api with CONTAINS function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488351/jpa-criteria-api-with-contains-function)